# mysql tries to connect to localhost at startup, [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, percona

When I start/restart the mysql service, I always see this row in the log:

> 2017-07-19T17:35:02.379166Z 5 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

What is it trying to do? And how can I set the user/password/host for this operation? (it should be `127.0.0.1` and not `localhost` because I have `skip_name_resolve=1`)

I already have a .my.cnf in my home folder, but mysql is running under the mysql user, so should I create a .my.cnf file in the mysql home? Would this be safe?

I'm using a Percona Server 5.7

Answer (score 0):

This is because the mysqladmin cannot login as root.

The guilty is this Systemd unit:

```
/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service
```

Which executes this command to see if the daemon is started properly:

```
ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
```

Which executes:

```
# mysqladmin ping         
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
# echo $?
0
```

The return value is 0 despite the error message so the daemon is marked as started.

Debian has a file which contains an user to execute unattended operations, to use this file explicitely the previous command must be executed in this manner:

```
mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping
```

After this explanation I can ignore the line in the error log.